# GCC в Arch вываливается в ошибку

Tags: c++, компиляция, gcc, archlinux

Собственно, вот проблема:

Компилирую любой код, взять хотя бы тот же Hello World

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Прогоняю его через gcc

```
gcc ./hello_world.cpp
```

И-и-и он вываливается в такой вот текст:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc4ZJJRS.o: предупреждение: перемещение указывает на «_ZSt4cout» из раздела только для чтения «.text»
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc4ZJJRS.o: в функции «main»:
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0xe): неопределённая ссылка на «std::cout»
/usr/bin/ld: hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x13): неопределённая ссылка на «std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)»
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc4ZJJRS.o: в функции «__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)»:
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x43): неопределённая ссылка на «std::ios_base::Init::Init()»
/usr/bin/ld: hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x58): неопределённая ссылка на «std::ios_base::Init::~Init()»
/usr/bin/ld: предупреждение: создаётся DT_TEXTREL в PIE
collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
```

Я не особый знаток gcc, первые две строчки наталкивают на мысль, что у него проблемы с доступом к /tmp, ради эксперимента запускаю через sudo - результат тот же.

Какую еще информацию прикрепить я не знаю.
Система, как уже написал, Arch, пакет gcc, установлен из AUR.

Comment: Вам нужен `g++` (для языка C++), а не `gcc` (для языка C) .

Comment: И зачем вы его из AUR ставили, он же в официальных репозиториях есть.

Comment: @eanmos из AUR ставил потому, что не умею писать PKGBUILD)

`gcc` ставит и `gcc`, и `g++`, но за вот этот момент спасибо, я их не различал

Comment: А зачем уметь? `pacman -S gcc` и все.

Comment: @eanmos опять глупая моя голова. Я AUR с официальными репозиториями тоже попутал)

Comment: Бывает :) (6 символов нужно)

Answer (score 1):

В общем, проблема была только в моей глупости, я использовал `gcc` (который для C), а нужно было `g++`, который для C++